# Pandas pattern match and csv conversion of dataFrame

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the below code which i'm using to parse my data from the text file thats contains the Multiple Fields and hundreds of columns names where i'm choosing the required fields at the time of pandas processing via read_csv which works fine, it it only works with encoding='cp1252' .
There are five key fields which i'm looking for as `['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version', 'Network Name']`,

In the pattern section which i'm using a variable `patt` i'm looking for  key words/strings as `"AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|Fedora|\?"` which i beleive doesn't care about the case sensitiveness.
which is get matched into the column `OS Version` but i'm using the litral `?` mark to match the `?` which is working but at the same time it also gets the `Windows 10 ???` which i only wants `?` if its there in the `OS Version` field.

**Secondly**, When its converting the `df2.to_csv` the columns are not delimited rather coming into one which later i'm delimitting manually, How we can ensure that each field is correctly process as a CSV file.

```
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################### END OF THE Display Settings ###################
patt = "AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|Fedora|\?"
col_names = ['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'CPU Model', 'CDN Version', 'OS Version', 'Kernel Version', 'LDAP Profile', 'Network Name']
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Panda/host.txt', delimiter = "\t", usecols=col_names, encoding='cp1252',  dtype='unicode')
df2 = df1[df1['OS Version'].str.contains(patt,  na=False)][['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version', 'Network Name']]
df2['Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].str.replace("*", "")
df2.to_csv("HostList_from_Surveys.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

## Below is the data sample Image for view:

[image]

### Below is again same data in text format in case to reproduce.

```
Hostname    IP Address  Aux Site    OS Version  Network Name
host01      192.168.1.1   yoko  RHEL 5.5    CISCO
host02      192.168.1.2   chelmsford    AIX 6.1 
host03      192.168.1.3   sanjose   RHEL 5.5    
host04      192.168.1.4   rosh  CentOS 6.8  CISCO
host05      192.168.1.5   noida3    CentOS 5.10 CISCO
host06      192.168.1.6   rosh  RHEL 6.5    CISCO
host07      192.168.1.7   noida3    RHEL 6.5    CISCO
host08      192.168.1.8   san jose  RHEL 6.5    CISCO
host09      192.168.1.9   noida3    RHEL 5.5    
host10      192.168.1.10      sophia    RHEL 5.5    AVAYA
host11      192.168.1.11      sanjose   RHEL 5.5    AVAYA
host12      192.168.1.12      sanjose   RHEL 5.3    AVAYA
host13      192.168.1.13      sanjose   RHEL 5.8    AVAYA
host14  192.168.1.14      sanjose   Ubuntu 14.04.1
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to match a `?` not enclosed with `?`s, use `patt = "AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|Fedora|(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)"`. To make it case insensitive, add `(?i)` at the start.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, appreciate you advice , lte me try this.. this is great indeed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, regex works but when i convert the df to csv data column are not properly aligned which late i used to do manually via csv  functions.

Comment: I do not quite get it, shall I post my solution or not?  Did it help?

Comment: Would appreciate if you post your solution.

Comment: Done, see below.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor for the answer, accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
patt = "(?s)AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|Fedora|(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)"
```

This pattern matches

- `(?s)` - the `re.DOTALL` option inline equivalent that makes `.` match line break chars
- `AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|Fedora` - one of the substring alternatives
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)` - a question mark not enclosed with other question marks.